# Firefox: open Files directly in MS Excel 365 (app)

Tags: windows-10, firefox, microsoft-excel-365

I'm using Firefox Quantum (V68) (Windows 10 1809) to access Google Mail through their Web-Interface (gmail.com).

When I choose to "download" an attached file, Firefox gives me the option either to `save it to disk` or to `open it with an application` including a list with available applications and the option to add new applications called `others`.

[image]

I want to open it directly but in case of an Excelfile (`.xlsx`) there is no entry for Excel in the "open with"-list. So I choose "others" and a dialog pops up to add another application:

[image: add appliction dialog]

However, Excel isn't in there by default and since I'm using the Excel365 App, there is no `exe-file` I can choose manually.

I created an app-shortcut and tried to choose it instead of the `exe-file` directly but this does not work since app-shortcuts do not show up in the dialog to choose an application manually (regular exe-shortcuts do).

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I figured it out a solution. When MS Excel because the standard application for the file type (in my case xlsx) in the OS, the "open with" standard option in Firefox becomes "TwinUI". Using that entry opens the file directly in Excel.

[image: "open with"-dialog]