# Excel is missing as standard app

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive

Excel (Office 365) is suddenly missing as a "standard app" (possibly after an update).

Although I associated xlsx-files with Excel within the windows settings ("choose default apps by file type"-settings-window):

[image]

it is not listed as a standard app ("set defaults by app-settings"-window):

[image]

As a result, opening Onedrive Excel files via a browser using the option "Open in Excel" does not work anymore. e.g. in Firefox I can not associate Excel to open the files/links. It's the same for all browsers I tried. I only get the option to choose Openoffice or the app store:

[image]

Although Firefox still has it's old entry to open the link/file with the Excel app but it only returns an error. Sorry for the non-english screenshot, it basically says there is no app associated with this action.

[image]

If I set Firefox to associate Onedrive Excel file-links directly with the Excel's executable (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE`), Excel opens but without loading the file from Onedrive. I get a general error message that the file can not be opened. Opening the file through Excel manually works fine (I can access the one drive folder via the open file dialog).

I tried the standard solutions like repairing, uninstalling and reinstalling office including using the removal tool which didn't help. I tired the whole process on a different system which works fine.

Any ideas where else to look or what else to try?

Additional Info 1: I can not install Office with the online installer, I have to choose the offline option (although terminates with an error office gets installed). Repair doesn't work either, currently it gives me the error code 30029-13 (but it was different before I did the offline installation).

Additional Info 2: I used to open the Onedrive files [from Firefox via TWINUI](https://superuser.com/questions/1479508/firefox-open-files-directly-in-ms-excel-365-app)

Additional Info 3: Excel Files saved locally on my PC open without problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it really surprising that absolutely noone on the internet found or took the time to find a solution for this exact problem that I actually also had with a particular user.

That user could open a OneDrive Word document inside his browser using "Open with app" (or whatever it's called) and Word installed on the machine would open (protocol MS-WORD was properly associated with the install app by Firefox) but not an Excel document.

And manually associating MS-EXCEL with *%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Office 15\root\Office15\EXCEL.EXE* in Firefox would give a similar error message to what OP got.

And indeed I looked into *Apps > Default Apps > Choose default apps by protocol* in Windows settings and MS-EXCEL wasn't there. But it was present into HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT when looking through the registry (that's where I found the idea for using "protocolhandler.exe" instead, see below).

My workaround was to associate MS-EXCEL with *%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Office 15\root\Office15\protocolhandler.exe* in Firefox. And miracle! Now OneDrive Excel links will open with Excel installed on the machine. I have no explanation to why it works that way but it works. If anyone has a better solution, I'm open.

Comment: How sent you? God? How ever, you are my hero! I was looking for a solution forever additionally spend hours with Microsoft support without any success...  did `protocolhandler.exe` show up in the reg or where did you get the idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to different browsers (such as Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome) and check if you can use "Open in Excel" from OneDrive Online smoothly. It can help me verify if the issue only occurs with Firefox.

You can go to "Choose default apps by protocol", Select Excel for "MS-EXCEL"(Url: Excel Protocol).

[image]

If the issue persists, try "Rest to the Microsoft recommended defaults".

[image]

In addition, considering that you have installed 3rd-party Office suite, to ignore its influence, you can temporarily uninstall LibreOffice and then perform an [Online Repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for your Office 365 from Control Panel.

Comment: Resetting the standard apps was a nice idea but I still don't get the option to open a file or an onedrive link with Excel (this also applied to "Choose default apps by protocol"). Interestingly the option for MS excel is gone completely from the protocol list without Openoffice. (By the way, the problem occurs with every browser - see my question).

Comment: BTW repairing office gives me an error - same as the installation routine (see the additional information at the bottom of my question).